# Pi camera viewing angle

Tags: camera, raspicam

I am using the following pi camera(6 numbers) for my 360 degree camera project. It is a 160 degree camera. My question is what will be the vertical angle? can that also be 160? I have to design a spherical mounting point and for that i need the complete angle (conical portion of a sphere) each camera covers. Can someone help?

Here is the link for the camera.
http://www.sainstore.de/camera-module-board-5mp-160-wide-angle-fish-eye-lenses-for-raspberry-pi.html/

Comment: Keep in mind that the new Sony 8MP camera was just announced.

Comment: Stitching images from fisheye lenses sounds challenging

Comment: Yes.It is.But i have to do it as a part of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High school trigonometry. The viewing angle is usually given as the angle along the diagonal. From that and the aspect ratio you can figure out the horizontal and vertical angles.

Comment: Oh. Thats a new info for me. Now I will try to figure it out. Thanks a lot